# Dealing with incorrectly encoded UTF-16 (?) in Java

Tags: java, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm doing some work on the [common crawl](http://www.commoncrawl.org/) dataset (a large web crawl) and I keep seeing a strange encoding schema I just can't work out how to deal with.

The pattern I'm seeing again and again is something like the sequence of bytes `50 6f 6b e9 6d 6f 6e` which I'm guessing is meant to represent `Pokémon`.

Now encoding schemas aren't my strongest point, but I don't know of any encoding where it's valid to represent the `é` as just `e9`.

It's a bit like [UTF-16][1] which would be `fe ff 00 50 00 6f 00 6b 00 e9 00 6d 00 6f 00 6e`

And it's definitely not UTF-8 which would be `50 6f 6b c3 a9 6d 6f 6e`

So I'm just after a way in Java to decode these bytes into a string, a library would be ideal.

`new String(bytes)` justifiably doesn't work and is rightly converting the `e9` to the replacement character `ef bf bd` (aka the dreaded �)

Any ideas on how to handle these?

**update**

I've ended up using the character set encoding detector provided in Apache Tika [2]. Works well.

[1] http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm

[2] http://tika.apache.org/0.8/api/org/apache/tika/parser/txt/CharsetDetector.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's either [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), the latter being essentially a superset of the former. Use either `new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1")` or `new String(bytes, "Windows-1252")`.

Comment: @matkelcey: You're welcome! I have to say, it makes me happy to see a competent programmer who sees non-Unicode input and has literally no idea what it might be. There was a time not so long ago when Unicode was the exception rather than the rule.